# Multilevel Navigation Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, navigation

I have a very complex navigation menu I am trying to create, it looks something like this:
[image]

Basically it's a 3 level navigation bar that has 2 parent tabs, when you hover over any of the tabs you should be able to see its child navigation levels and when you hover out you see what you are currently on.

Another problem is that the two parent tabs have two different color themes, parent tab 1 being blue with all its child levels blue and the parent tab 2 is green etc..

I'm very confused about how I should do this, maybe nested divs?
Are there any plugins that will might my life a lot easier?

Comment: can you write your example in jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

Many samples are avaialble in internet but you need to modify according to your requirement.
Some examples are avialble:

http://jsfiddle.net/elusien/PayFw/8/

http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/200-Really-simple-hover-menus-with-jQuery

http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/wp-content/uploads/file/jquery-sliding-menu/#

Answer (score 1):

Something like *[jQuery Drop Line Tabs](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/item/jquery_drop_line_tabs/)* might work for this situation.  It's a jQuery plugin that allows for the multi-level navigation that you have in your question's image.  Here's a link to the plugin (and there is a live demo on that page, as well,) if you would like to check it out: [jQuery Drop Line Tabs](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/item/jquery_drop_line_tabs/).

If that doesn't work out... searching around online is bringing up a lot of [menu](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/38-jquery-and-css-drop-down-multi-level-menu-solutions/) [plugin](http://devsnippets.com/article/reviews/10-brilliant-multi-level-navigation-menu-techniques.html) [tutorials](http://speckyboy.com/2009/06/08/24-css-in-some-cases-with-jquery-navigation-and-menu-tutorials/).

Hope that at least gets you pointed in a plugin direction for this...!